# How to solve intermittent "Error: Server terminated early with status 69"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am running my tests using selenium-webdriver, randomly some intermediate test fail with "Error: Server terminated early with status 69" and then it continues fine for next test.

So I wish to know,

1. where should I look for the meaning of status code 69
2. if it means Unhandled error (as on next line), what can I do further to debug the cause

thx

```
  console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:157
    Unhandled error

  console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:158
    Error: Server terminated early with status 69
        at earlyTermination.catch.e (PATH\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\remote\index.js:252:52)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
    From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
        at Function.createSession (PATH\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
        at Function.createSession (PATH\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\firefox\index.js:521:41)
        at createDriver (PATH\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:170:33)
        at Builder.build (PATH\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\index.js:645:16)
        at Object.get (PATH\src\setup\web\driver.ts:13:9)
        at Object.<anonymous> (PATH\src\setup\web\setup.ts:9:19)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at PATH\src\setup\web\setup.ts:7:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (PATH\src\setup\web\setup.ts:3:12)
        at Object.beforeAll (PATH\src\setup\web\setup.ts:18:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (PATH\src\setup\common.ts:215:17)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at PATH\src\setup\common.ts:7:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (PATH\src\setup\common.ts:3:12)
        at Object.<anonymous>.beforeAll (PATH\src\setup\common.ts:213:22)
        at Object.asyncJestLifecycle (PATH2\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\jasmine_async.js:63:37)
        at resolve (PATH2\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queue_runner.js:56:12)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (PATH2\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queue_runner.js:43:19)
        at promise.then (PATH2\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queue_runner.js:87:41)
        at <anonymous>
```

Comment: The issue appears to be caused by geckodriver. https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/b4ebbe90ae4d0468fe6232bb4ce90699738c8125/testing/geckodriver/src/main.rs#55-59

Comment: Possibly server is unable to bind to default port, since prior instance has not fully release the port yet.